# Showing a form in a WCF instance

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Currently we have an application running on a local machine (Process 1)
We also have a WCF webservice running on a local machine (Process 2)

- Process 1 makes a call to Process 2
- Process 2 then needs to display a WinForm to the user.
- The problem is that the WinForm displayed by Process 2 is hidden behind forms displayed by Process 1.
- If I pass in the window handle of Process 1 to Process 2 to use as the parent window handle the window becomes unresponsive.

Is there any way that Process 2 can display a window that is on top of already displayed windows in Process 1?

I've expiremented with calls to the User32.dll without success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are Process1 and Process2 running under the same user account?

Comment: I've tried TopMost but it doesn't work. I think the reason is that it's two different processes and TopMost only works within a process. Process1 and Process2 are running the same user account.